# NSURLSession, синхронная загрузка

Tags: objective-c, xcode, сессия

В данный момент у меня асинхронная загрузка(загрузка не останавливающая программу), мне же нужно, чтобы в этом участке кода программа точно загрузила данные и только после продолжала(синхронная загрузка), как это реализовать?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:lineURLresult]; // URL
NSURLSessionDataTask *downloadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession]
                                      dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                          id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
                                          {
                                              if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] && error == nil){

                                                  id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
                                                  [_tableViewData addObject:object];
                                                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                      // обновление UI
                                                  });
                                              }
                                          }
                                      }];
```

Answer (score 1):

Перед началом запроса, программно наложите сверху View, лучше всего размытый (это заблокирует нажатия на элементы ниже) и добавьте бесконечный прогресс-бар.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView* workView;

self.workView = [[UIView alloc] init];
self.workView.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view addSubview:self.workView];
self.workView.center = self.view.center;
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.workView]; // отправляем на передний план
```

При получении ответа от сервера или ошибки - удалите этот View и прогресс-бар.

```
[self.workView removeFromSuperview];
```

Как добавлять и удалять прогресс-бар не стал описывать, выберите подходящий на [cocoacontrols](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/)